# what will be the Regular expression?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-lex

What will be the regular expression for salary i.e "2 lakhs" or "3.4 lakhs" or "3.4" in python for Amazon Lex?
I tried this

```
ctc_regex = re.compile(r'^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})"lakhs"?$')
```

Comment: can you please elaborate your question? are you just trying to match [2 lakhs, 3.4 lakhs, 3.4] or all values in between. If these are just three values you are trying to compare use list of values and comaprision opereator instead of regex.

Comment: @Pooja these values are just the examples. I need lex to accept all the possible values that the user can input for CTC slot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, replace quotes around `lakhs` on braces and add space in it. Also, make point and numbers after it optional too.

`^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]{1,2})?( lakhs)?$`

See test here
https://regex101.com/r/5DAo6S/1